# java data access: is this good style of java data access code, or is it too much try finally?

Tags: java, data-access-layer

Is this good style of java data access code, or is it too much try finally ?

```
public List<Item> getItems() throws ItemException {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    try {
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ....");
            try {
                ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Item item = new Item();
                        item.setItemNo(rs.getString("item_id"));
                        // ...
                        items.add(item);
                    }
                } finally {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } finally {
                pStmt.close();
            }
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ItemException(e);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: i would suggest you to go for hibernate. It has hell lot of features.
Aarons code look good but if you are using JDBC every time. You will end up creating lot of connection to the database which may take a toll on the applications performance.

Comment: `ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();` should be `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare it to my code:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try
{
    con = ds.getConnection();
    pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ....");
    rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Item item = new Item();

        item.setItemNo(rs.getString("item_id"));
        ...

        items.add(item);
    }
}
finally {
    rs = DBUtil.close (rs);
    pStmt = DBUtil.close (rs);
    con = DBUtil.close (rs);
}
```

Here is what `close()` looks like:

```
public static ResultSet close (ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close ();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace (); 
        // Or use your favorite logging framework.
        // DO NOT THROW THIS EXCEPTION OR IT WILL
        // HIDE EXCEPTIONS IN THE CALLING METHOD!!
    }
    return null; // Make sure no one uses this anymore
}
```

[EDIT] You'll need to copy this code for the other types.

I also moved all this into a helper class called `DBOp` so I just have to override `processRow(ResultSet row)` to do the actual processing and I can omit all that boilerplate code. In Java 5, the constructor of `DBOp` reads:

```
public DBOp (Logger log, DataSource ds, String sql, Object... param)
```

I'm passing in the logger so I can show which instance is actually polling data.

Comment: I think you forgot to change the parameter to close() in the second to calls.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make one copy of this code per JDBC type :( I wish Sun would have made them implement `Closeable`.

Comment: If getConnection() obtains a Connection from a pool, then it should not be closed.

Also, I think closing the statement automatically closes the ResultSet too.

Comment: @Adriann: This depends on the pool implementation. Those I use will return a connection to the pool when I close it. This way, my code is the same no matter whether I use pooling or not.

Answer (score 2):

According to the API doc, [Statements](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) and [ResultSets](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) are implicitly closed with the Connection, so yes - 2 of those try/finally-blocks are unnecessary (and very ugly). Explicitly closing Statements may be useful when you're keeping a single Connection around for a lot of queries, in order to reduce memory usage.

Comment: In anything but the most simple code, you should close them manually or they will hang around.

Comment: No. If you make sure the Connection is closed, all that might hang around are the objects themselves, and closing them manually will not prevent that either.

Answer (score 1):

... and you should not close the connection in that `getItems()` method. It looks like, you stored your Connection object in that `ds` object. So you should leave it to `ds` to close it. Otherwise, there is a risk that ds returns an already closed connection with the getConnection() method, and I assume, that's an unwanted and unexpected behaviour ;)

Comment: ... unless the `ds` object happens to be a `DataSource`, of course. Then you'll have to close the connection when you are done with it. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html

Comment: @Dirk, good catch, and the (too) short variable name is a hint that you're right. I thought of the traditional DriverManager where you get the connection through in a static method.