# Reduce nesting when cleaning up multiple non-Closeable resources

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, java-7, try-with-resources

I have a `Closeable` that needs to clean up multiple resources in the `close()` method. Each resource is a `final` class that I cannot modify. None of the included resources are `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable`. I also need to call `super.close()`. So it appears that I cannot handle any of the resources* using `try-with-resources`. My current implementation looks something like this:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        super.close();
    } finally {
        try {
            container.shutdown();
        } catch (final ShutdownException e) {
            throw new IOException("ShutdownException: ", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                client.closeConnection();
            } catch (final ConnectionException e) {
                throw new IOException("Handling ConnectionException: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd prefer a solution with less crazy nesting but I can't figure out how to take advantage of `try-with-resources` or any other features to do that. [Code sandwiches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254862/advice-on-nested-java-try-finally-code-sandwiches) don't seem to help here since I'm not using the resources at all, just cleaning them up. Since the resources aren't `Closeable`, it's unclear how I could use the recommended solutions in [Java io ugly try-finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699209/java-io-ugly-try-finally-block).

* Even though the `super` class is `Closeable`, I cannot use `super` in a `try-with-resources` because `super` is just syntactic sugar and not a real Java `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a good (albeit unorthodox) case for `try-with-resources`. First, you'll need to create some interfaces:

```
interface ContainerCleanup extends AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    void close() throws ShutdownException;
}
interface ClientCleanup extends AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    void close() throws ConnectionException;
}
```

If these interfaces are only used in the current class, I'd recommend making them inner interfaces. But they also work as public utility interfaces if you use them in multiple classes.

Then in your `close()` method you can do:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    final Closeable ioCleanup = new Closeable() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            YourCloseable.super.close();
        }
    };
    final ContainerCleanup containerCleanup = new ContainerCleanup() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws ShutdownException {
            container.shutdown();
        }
    };
    final ClientCleanup clientCleanup = new ClientCleanup() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws ConnectionException {
            client.closeConnection();
        }
    };
    
    // Resources are closed in the reverse order in which they are declared,
    // so reverse the order of cleanup classes.
    // For more details, see Java Langauge Specification 14.20.3 try-with-resources:
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3
    try (clientCleanup; containerCleanup; ioCleanup) {
        // try-with-resources only used to ensure that all resources are cleaned up.
    } catch (final ShutdownException e) {
        throw new IOException("Handling ShutdownException: ", e);
    } catch (final ConnectionException e) {
        throw new IOException("Handling ConnectionException: ", e);
    }
}
```

Of course this becomes even more elegant and concise with Java 8 lambdas:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    final Closeable ioCleanup = () -> super.close();
    final ContainerCleanup containerCleanup = () -> container.shutdown();
    final ClientCleanup clientCleanup = () -> client.closeConnection();
    
    // Resources are closed in the reverse order in which they are declared,
    // so reverse the order of cleanup classes.
    // For more details, see Java Langauge Specification 14.20.3 try-with-resources:
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3
    try (clientCleanup; containerCleanup; ioCleanup) {
        // try-with-resources only used to ensure that all resources are cleaned up.
    } catch (final ShutdownException e) {
        throw new IOException("Handling ShutdownException: ", e);
    } catch (final ConnectionException e) {
        throw new IOException("Handling ConnectionException: ", e);
    }
}
```

This removes all the crazy nesting and it has the added benefit of saving the suppressed exceptions. In your case, if `client.closeConnection()` throws, we'll never know if the previous methods threw any exceptions. So the stacktrace will look something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Handling ConnectionException: 
        at Main$YourCloseable.close(Main.java:69)
        at Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: Main$ConnectionException: Failed to close connection.
        at Main$Client.closeConnection(Main.java:102)
        at Main$YourCloseable.close(Main.java:67)
        ... 1 more
```

By using `try-with-resources`, the Java compiler generates code to handle the suppressed exceptions, so we'll see them in the stacktrace and we can even handle them in the calling code if we want to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to close super.
        at Main$SuperCloseable.close(Main.java:104)
        at Main$YourCloseable.access$001(Main.java:35)
        at Main$YourCloseable $1.close(Main.java:49)
        at Main$YourCloseable.close(Main.java:68)
        at Main.main(Main.java:22)
        Suppressed: Main$ShutdownException: Failed to shut down container.
                at Main$Container.shutdown(Main.java:140)
                at Main$YourCloseable$2.close(Main.java:55)
                at Main$YourCloseable.close(Main.java:66)
                ... 1 more
        Suppressed: Main$ConnectionException: Failed to close connection.
                at Main$Client.closeConnection(Main.java:119)
                at Main$YourCloseable$3.close(Main.java:61)
                at Main$YourCloseable.close(Main.java:66)
                ... 1 more
```

#### Caveats

1. **If the order of clean up matters**, you need to declare your resource cleanup classes/lambdas in the **reverse** order that you want them run. I recommend adding a comment to that effect (like the one I provided).
2. If any exceptions are **suppressed**, the `catch` block for that exception will **not** execute. In those cases, it's probably better change the lambdas to handle the exception:

   ```
   final Closeable containerCleanup = () -> {
       try {
           container.shutdown();
       } catch (final ShutdownException e) {
           // Handle shutdown exception
           throw new IOException("Handling shutdown exception:", e);
       }
   }
   ```

   Handling the exceptions inside the lambda does start to add some nesting, but the nesting isn't recursive like the original so it'll only ever be one level deep.

Even with those caveats, I believe the pros greatly outweigh the cons here with the automatic suppressed exception handling, conciseness, elegance, readability, and reduced nesting (especially if you have 3 or more resources to clean up).